# How to detect which building is in front of which in an isometric map

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to develop a city game where people can put buildings in an Isometric map, and there are characters walking around. Yet I found it's hard to figure out which building is in front of which to always show the buildings in front over the buildings at the back. (same idea applies for the characters. i.e. they should get hidden when they are behind some buildings)

So I'm wondering if any developers here have had a similar problem and is willing to shall the solution algorithm.

Any input will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sort your sprites based off of your y position.